# Problems understanding 0th relative cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute $H^{i}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)$.

For that, I have used the long exact sequence of relative cohomology:

$0\to H^0(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)\to H^0(\mathbb{R}^2)\to H^0(\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)\to H^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)\to H^1(\mathbb{R}^2) \to H^1(\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)\to H^2(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)\to 0$.

Now, $\mathbb{R}^2-S^1$= $A\cup B$ where $B$ is contractible and $A$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. Therefore, $$H^0(\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)=\mathbb{Z}^2, H^1(\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)=\mathbb{Z}, H^2(\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)=0.$$

So, $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ and I also have $$0\to H^0(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)\to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2\to H^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)\to 0.$$

Nevertheless, I do not know how to compute $H^0(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)$. I know that if $X$ is a space, $H^{0}(X)=\mathbb{Z}^n$ where $n$ is the number of connected components of $X$. But what does it mean in the case of relative cohomology? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Taking reduced cohomology can be more straightforward and notice that the reduced cohomology of a pair is the same as the unreduced one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$H^0(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)$ is, from the long exact sequence, the kernel of $H^0(\mathbb{R}^2)\to H^0(\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)$.

But this map sends the cocycle that sends every point to $1$ (which corresponds to $1\in \mathbb{Z}$) to the cocycle that does the same thing (and corresponds to $(1,1)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$), therefore it is injective.

Another way to see that it must be injective, is that it's a map $\mathbb{Z\to Z}^2$ and such a map is either injective or $0$ (can you prove that ? ). Now it can't be $0$ ( to see that, though, you must probably argue in a way similar to the one above, so I don't know if it's really that helpful)

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now! So then $H^0(X,A)$ is almost always $0$, no? In all the examples that I can imagine now, that happens. Moreover, in this case I would obtain that $H^0(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)=0$ and $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2-S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$, right? Does the last thing make sense? Is there a geometric interpretation to convince myself?

Comment: Well in the nice cases, yes, but imagine that $X$ isn't path-connected but $A$ is, then $H^0(X)\to H^0(A)$ can't be injective, and the long exact sequence tells us that $H^0(X,A)$ isn't $0$ in this case. But it is the case that very often $0$th (co)homology (whether relative or absolute) isn't very interesting.  You are right about the isomorphisms you obtain, yes.

Comment: I don't know about geometric interpretation, but the relative cocycles are cochains on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that vanish on paths whose both extremities lie in $\mathbb{R}^2-S^1$, so they vanish on pretty much everything except the circle, so you would expect it to look like $H^1(S^1)$